# Bayesian Regression : Marginal Posterior Demonstration

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, regression, bayesian

(n.b. : I am learning Bayesian Statistics)

In the case of a normal linear regression :
$$y=X\theta+\epsilon$$
$$\ y=(y_1,...,y_n) : \text{Observed data },
\quad\theta=(\theta_1,...,\theta_p) : \text{ parameters },
\quad\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma I)$$
The likelihood is :
$$l(\theta,\sigma^2\mid y)=
\frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{n/2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y-X\theta)^T(y-X\theta)}
$$
A non informative prior is used
$$ \pi(\theta,\sigma^2)=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}
$$

The marginal prior $$\pi(\theta\mid y)=\int l(\theta,\sigma^2\mid y)\cdot\pi(\theta,\sigma^2)\,d\sigma$$

Until here, it is clear. But after, I read :

> the marginal prior is a scale and shifted multivariate t-distribution with $n-p$ degrees of freedom, the mean is $(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$, and the covariance matrix is $\frac{n-p}{n-p-2}\cdot s^2\cdot(X^TX)^{-1}$

without explanation.

Could someone give me the demonstration or where can I find it ?

Thanks for help and answer.

Comment: That should be obvious from evaluating $\int_0^\infty\gamma^n\exp(-\frac12\gamma^2 q(y,\theta))\,\mathrm{d}\gamma$, $\gamma=\sigma^{-1}$.

Comment: Likelihood is the probability of getting your data given your parameters.  That should be $L(y|\theta, \sigma^2)$ not the other way around.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor No, that part is fine as written in the post.

Comment: Thanks. I guess "likelihood" has more definitions than I know about.

Comment: @user1034138. Thanks for help. I will try but it is not so obvious for me.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor The $Y$ has distribution depending on the parameters $\theta,\sigma^2$, i.e., pdf $f(y\mid\theta,\sigma^2)$, so the likelihood function is $l(\theta,\sigma^2\mid y)$.

Comment: @Stef1611 When you integrate $\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}\sigma^{-n}\exp(-\frac1{2\sigma^2}q(y,\theta))\,\mathrm{d}\sigma$ ($q=(y-X\theta)^T(y-X\theta)$ a psd quadratic in $\theta$) you get $\propto q(y,\theta)^{\text{some power}}$ which you should recognise as basically the pdf of a $t$-distribution.